# Como puedo puedo ver si un dato de un vector esta en otro ya definido? C

Tags: c

he intentado ver si al ingresar un valor en un vector, dicho valor esta contenido en otro vector ya definido. por ejemplo: tengo un vector[3]={10,20,30} y otro vectorComparacion[5]={0,0,0,0,0}, si ingreso un valor en la posición 0 del vectorComparacion quiero ver si ese valor esa dentro del otro vector.
he intentado diversas formas pero no logro conseguirlo.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int vector[3];
    int vectorDos[5];

    for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
        printf("digite valor:> ");
        scanf("%d",&vector[i]);
    }
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<3;j++){
            printf("digite segundo valor:> ");
            scanf("%d",&vectorDos[i]);
                if((vectorDos[i])!=(vector[j])){
                    printf("malo");
                }else{
                    printf("bueno");
                }
        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba algo como esto, es una manera de hacerlo, declaras a `j` en el primer `for` para no perder su valor después de salir del segundo `for`. Preguntas si alguno de tus valores del vector anterior es igual al valor que acabas de ingresar para guardar en el vector actual, si es así imprimes "bueno" y sales del ciclo, en caso de que no, `j` llegara hasta 3 porque como no encontró al menos uno igual, siguió el ciclo hasta ser 3, significa que es "malo",para eso es el `if` que se encuentra después.

Espero te haya sido de utilidad.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int vector[3];
    int vectorDos[5];

    for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
        printf("digite valor:> ");
        scanf("%d",&vector[i]);
    }

    for(int i=0, j=0;i<5;i++){
        printf("digite segundo valor:> ");
        scanf("%d",&vectorDos[i]);

        for(j=0;j<3;j++){
            if((vectorDos[i])==(vector[j])){
                printf("bueno\n");
                break;
            }
        }
        if(j==3){
            printf("malo\n");
        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Debes comparar el numero que ingresas para el segundo vector, con cada elemento del primer vector de la siguiente manera:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int vector[3];
    int vectorDos[5];

    for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
        printf("digite valor:> ");
        scanf("%d",&vector[i]);
    }

    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
        printf("digite segundo valor:> "); //Pides el siguiente valor
        scanf("%d",&vectorDos[i]);

        for(int j=0;j<3;j++){
            if((vectorDos[i])==(vector[j])){ //Comparas ese valor con todos los valores del primer vector
                printf("Existe\n"); //Si existe, imprime el mensaje y ya no sigue comparando.
                break;//Si deseas imprimir 'existe' cada vez que aparezca, quita este break
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```